# How did Don Corleone and Luca Brasi influence Johnny Fontana's bandleader?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather

In the opening wedding scene, Michael tells Kay a story about Johnny Fontana wanting to be released from his band.  He explains that after an hour of negotiation between the bandleader, and the Don and Luca Brasi, that he was released for a certified check of $1,000.00.

I am wondering if this story is recounted anywhere.  Specifically because, while Luca was known for brute force, the Don was known to have more finesse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you rewatch the scene. Michael explains to Kay EXACTLY how Don Corleone persuaded the bandleader.

> MICHAEL
>
> Well, when Johnny was first starting out, he was signed to this personal service contract; with a big band leader. And as his career got better and better, he wanted to get out of it.
>
> Now, Johnny is my father's godson. And my father went to see this band leader, and he offered him $10,000 to let Johnny go. But the band leader said no. So the next day, my father went to see him; only this time with Luca Brasi. And within an hour, he signed a release, for a certified check for $1,000.
>
> KAY
>
> How'd he do that?
>
> MICHAEL
>
> My father made him an offer he couldn't refuse.
>
> KAY
>
> What was that?
>
> MICHAEL
>
> Luca Brasi held a gun to his head, and my father assured him that either his brains -- or his signature -- would be on the contract.

Comment: Apologies. You are correct.  I didn't do my diligence.